# Significance of Law of reciprocal proportions

Tags: history-of-chemistry

The laws of conservation of mass, definite proportions multiple proportions makes sense and were definitely useful for chemists in the early days of modern chemistry. 
The [law of reciprocal proportions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_reciprocal_proportions) states that

> If element A combines with element B and also with C, then, if B and C combine together, the proportion by weight in which they do so will be simply related to the weights of B and C which separately combine with a constant weight of A.

I don't understand how the law of reciprocal proportions is useful. It seems too unnecessarily complex for someone to intuitively come up with.
Is there any intuition/specific reason that Jeremias Richter came up with it?

Comment: This law has a historical importance. It was stated before the discovery of the universal notions of valence and of mole. It was important for the scientists around Dalton and Berzelius to realize that the amount of oxygen and nitrogen in various oxides were exactly in the ratio 1.000 to 2, or 1.000 to 1, or 2.000 to 1, and never 1.007 to 2, or 0.982 to 1, or 2.17 to 1.  Today it seems obvious. It was not obvious in the beginning of the 19th century. It was even surprising. But this law is no more of any use today.

Comment: I think you are talking about the law of multiple proportions, my question is about a different law

Comment: It would help to prevent wrong assumptions and interpretations if you explicitly formulated the law in the question. Omitted question info is usually expensively paid for by much longer clarification chain. Well elaborated questions prevent this.

Comment: *As an example, 1 gram of sodium (Na = A) is observed to combine with either 1.54 grams of chlorine (Cl = B) or 5.52 grams of iodine (I = C). (These ratios correspond to the modern formulas NaCl and NaI). The ratio of these two weights is 5.52/1.54 = 3.58. It is also observed that 1 gram of chlorine reacts with 1.19 g of iodine. This ratio of 1.19 obeys the law because it is a simple fraction (1/3) of 3.58. (This is because it corresponds to the formula ICl3, which is one known compound of iodine and chlorine.) Similarly, hydrogen, carbon, and oxygen follow the law of reciprocal proportions.*

Comment: These laws were originally empirical rules based on observations, as the discrete atomic matter theory and molar masses were to come yet. Berzelius: *When two substances, A and B have an affinity for two others, C and D, the ratio of the quantities C and D which saturate the same amount of A is the same as that between the quantities C and D which saturate the same amount of B.*

Comment: OK. I understand. I will try to rewrite Richter's law in the case of A = H, B = Oxygen and C = Carbon. It gives :  $4 g$ $\ce{H}$ reacts with $12 g$ $\ce{C}$ to produce methane. The same amount $4 g$ H reacts with $2·16 = 32 g$ Oxygen to produce water. So Richter's law states that if $\ce{C}$ reacts with $\ce{O}$, this reaction will involve $12 g$$\ce{ C}$ with $32 g \ce{O}$, or a multiple of $32 g$ $\ce{O}$. Apparently this law was not obvious in the 19th century.

Comment: Oh, so the law would help in predicting how 2 elements combine if we know how they both combine with a 3rd element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After defining the law of definite proportions and law of multiple proportions, we could successfully understand how two elements combine together.

The question arose: *What about if we took more than two elements?*. So, J. Richter came up with the law of reciprocal proportions, which is infact intuitive, I guess you are understanding it unintuitively yourself. It states

> If two elements combine with a third element, then the ratio of masses of the two elements for unit mass of third element, is a simple ratio of whole numbers.

It is not that complicated; it is just like the law of multiple proportions *i.e.*,

> If two elements combine in more than one way, the the ratio of mass of either element for unit mass of other element, is a simple ratio of whole numbers.

Now, you see the law of reciprocal proportions is nothing but *kinda* extended version of law of multiple proportions for three elements.

Hope this is clear :)

Comment: The law states that the ratio of the 2 elements in the compound which they make is a equal or a simple multiple of the ratio with which they combine with the unit 3rd element, but I think you have made me understand how it works

Comment: Yeah, I realised your statement was unnecessarily complicated, and I got what was unclear to you. So, posted this. :)

Answer (score 1):

The comments certainly clarify the law of reciprocal proportions and are an excellent tutorial on how to write a good question but sheds little light on your question “Is there any intuition/specific reason that Jeremias Richter came up with it?”

From reading a number of short bibliographic sketches about Richter it appears his primary interest was mathematics.  The title of his doctoral thesis was, roughly translated, The use of Mathematics in Chemistry  [https://www.encyclopedia.com/science/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/richter-jeremias-benjamin].  His study of quantitative relationships in the neutralization of acids by bases lead to the law of equivalents. [https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Jeremias+Benjamin+Richter ]

Based on these and similar biographical notes one might argue that he arrived at the law of reciprocal proportions *not through “intuition” at all but rather through an empirically based and numbers driven approach.*  When a mathematician sees a pattern or consistency in “the numbers” they then might be seek to understand the natural forces giving rise to their observations.

A modern and well written example of “math driving science” can be found here. https://www.quantamagazine.org/geometry-reveals-how-the-world-is-assembled-from-cubes-20201119/ “Scientists Uncover the Universal Geometry of Geology”

Comment: just to confirm, you mean 'law of _reciprocal proportions_ right? not _multiple proportions_ .

Comment: Thank you for your careful reading and catching this, yes I was focusing on the question of reciprocal proportions and will edit my answer to make that clear.